# Is there an elegant way to ask the hub the max no of browser instances a node registered with it can run?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

So my grid can get nodes on the fly and at any point of time I want to know the max no of chrome/firefox instances a particular node can run by asking the hub server. I think i can do that by scraping the grid console page but is there some other way to go about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the possible answers. The answers to this one  are -

1. Write your own servlet by pulling the selenium server code.
2. Scrape through the grid console and look for chrome.png matches.

I have done the 2nd and it is working fine.